# Accidentally enabled Firewall - SSH connections to port 22 are refused

Tags: linux, azure, ssh, firewall

I have a remote Azure Ubuntu VM where firewall wasn't enabled. While changing the configurations I accidentally enabled the firewall but forgot to allow port 22 for SSH. Only port 443 is allowed in firewall.

It's a very lame mistake but I cannot SSH into my VM. The SSH connection is refused every time. Is there a way out of this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately currently (August 2016) it is not possible to do that on Azure. The only way to fix it would be to download the VHDs for the VM, boot them locally in Hyper-V, VMConnect to them, fix the problem and upload them back to Azure.

It is an often requested feature here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines/suggestions/3761826-virtual-machine-console-access

Answer (score 0):

Most VM providers provide a form of console access via the control panel where your VM instances are managed. This usually requires you to log into the control panel. The console then allows access the same way a screen and keyboard would. You can use this to open port 22 in your firewall.

Comment: Azure unfortunately does not support console access. See https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines/suggestions/3761826-virtual-machine-console-access

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "[CustomScriptExtension](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-extensions-features/)" VM extension to run the command necessary to repair the firewall rule.